# How to set EnviromentVariables in windows runtime c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, environment-variables, winrt-xaml

I have problem with setting environment variables using C# in windows store app.

I need to modify some environment variables on some scenario, please find the example in other platform, i can able to do this using

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sss")
```

or

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("sss", null);
```

Thank in advance,

Comment: Suresh, as it is written it is hard to understand the issue. Are you getting an exception?

Comment: How to set the EnvironmentVariable in c# for windows-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't as a windows Store app runs in a sandbox and therefore is not allowed to change system settings

Comment: Thanks for writing us.

Comment: I can able to maintain the value in local storage, using the     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings